# What is the simplest way to scrape Javascript webpages in the cloud?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, scrapy, splash-screen

Currently, there are a set up of web pages that I scrape using python. I use `scrapy_splash` to render javascript.

I would like to move this scraping task to the cloud so that it can run 24x7 and scrape periodically on a schedule.

What would be the easiest way to do this? Looking for options that are free or a couple of dollars a month. Thanks

Comment: You can use a virtual machine supported by google. You get free $300 credit when signing up and the cost of running a VM depends on the specs you choose. You can set up everything over there.

Answer (score 0):

There's [Google Cloud Free Program](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) - it includes [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) perios with 300 USD credit valid for 90 days just as [me.limes said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820103/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-scrape-javascript-webpages-in-the-cloud#comment125207843_70820103):

> - **90-day, $300 Free Trial**: New Google Cloud and Google Maps Platform users can take advantage of a 90-day trial period that includes $300 in free Cloud Billing credits to explore and evaluate Google Cloud and Google Maps Platform products and services. You can use these credits toward one or a combination of products.

This may be just what you need to test your solution when you move it to the cloud without worrying too much about the costs.

What you really can use to run your python script is the [Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier):

> - **Free Tier**: All Google Cloud customers can use select Google Cloud products—like Compute Engine, Cloud Storage, and BigQuery—free of charge, within specified monthly usage limits. When you stay within the Free Tier limits, these resources are not charged against your Free Trial credits or to your Cloud Billing account's payment method after your trial ends.

This means that you can for example run a single `e2-micro` VM instance continously without incurring any additional charges (even after 90 day free trial).

Or you can run your script in app engine - you get 28 hours per days of "F" instances (which should be way more than you need).

There's also 1GB / day of agress traffic included in this. Look at the links in my answer and read the documentation which described in detail what you can use for free.

All the products and limits are however subject to change at any time but you will be notified beforehand if such change is going to take place.